# How to open a 3D-PDF file with an external app via Android Intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I have downloaded a 3D-PDF file within my Android app, which I want to open in an external app via an Intent. I'm using "3D PDF Reader" as the external app.

This is the source code in Java:

```
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            showMessage("Keine App zur Anzeige von PDF-Dokumenten gefunden!");
        }
```

And the error message is: "Sorry, 3D content could not be loaded from this PDF. The document is either secured or contains no 3D content."

I am able to show normal PDF files in an external app with this code. When I use the app "Total Commander" (a file manager app) to click on the 3D-PDF, which was downloaded by my app, I am able to load the 3D-PDF file in the external app ("3D PDF Reader"). So it must be possible to achieve my goal.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read through the documentation you linked. In my code, I provide temporary permissions for my file to the external app with FileProvider. This works for normal PDF documents, but not for 3D-PDFs. I'm not specifying the type of the file in FileProvider, so I think the problem must be elsewhere. Do you want to see the code that relates to FileProvider?

Comment: Try without Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

Comment: `am able to show normal PDF files` Are the normal ones from the same directory as the 3D one?

Comment: After the error message does the viewer display something? Does it stop/end? Plese show the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()`. Are you on Android 10/11 ?

Comment: Thank you for your ideas @blackapps. They got me in the right direction. I initialized the file name, which includes the current time, twice. Once before loading the file and once before presenting it. With normal PDFs, the time span between loading and presenting the file was zero. But 3D-PDFs take longer to load,